# Rest API or Semi Rest API

Tags: php, api, rest

I have a controller for `ProductController`. I have 4 standard methods bound to respective HTTP methodslike

```
public function index() // GET
public function create() // POST
public function update() // PUT
public function destroy() //DELETE
```

So far so good, but i have to make few other functions like getProductsByCategory, getProductsAttributes() etc etc. After implementing this, Will my API still be called REST ? If not than how can i handle these requirements

Thanks

Comment: The issue you've described has nothing to do with your service being RESTful or not.

Answer (score 2):

Resource URI for getProductsByCategory(...):

```
GET /products?category=books HTTP/1.1
Host: service.org
```

Resource URI for getProductsAttributes():

```
GET /products/bmw-528i/attributes HTTP/1.1
Host: service.org
```

How you implement handling of these request URIs is a implementation detail. If you are using some framework, you can do something like this:

```
Routes::add("/products/{product-id}/attributes", function($request, $response) {
    // do something here
});
```

But it is a detail that can not affect RESTfullness of your service.

Answer (score 1):

First off, REST is not a strict standard. The methods you posted comply the REST conventions but a REST service must have several other properties. The two most important ones are:

- statelessness: no session, no cookies, authorization on a per-request basis
- GET requeste never change any resource

There are other ones, feel free to edit or add in the comments.

The way i see such operations on resources implemented most of the time is:

`/<resource-name>/<product-id>/<operation>`

For example:

```
GET /product/<product-id>
GET /product/<product-id>/related
POST /product/<product-id>/purchase
GET /categories/tools
```

Comment: How would you describe `getProductByCateogry` ?

Comment: getProductByCategory or getProduct**s**ByCategory? I'd implement the latter one as `GET /category/tools/products`